# Where do you defend / protest a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've recently had a question closed (as a dupe), which is fair enough, but I wad wondering where is the best place to defend it? Meta, comments on the original question or somewhere else?

I've popped a comment on my original question But it occurred to me that the people who matter (mods) probably won't re-visit the question, so won't see the comment. (and I suspect the SE engine won't alert anyone?) But to protest on meta would seem a little over the top (I want to discuss the closed question, not have a tantrum*) and presumably we don't want meta flooded with closed-question rants?

*this question is only tangentally related to the other, and definitely not a tantrum ;)

Comment: Linking the question you are beefing over would help.

Comment: Noted, unfortunately I'm away from home and this entire encounter is via my phone. (Copy and paste is tricky sometimes)

Comment: er.. here? but where's the link to your question?

Comment: Allow me, http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/how-do-you-maintain-pacing-close-to-a-campaign-climax-when-a-number-of-players-ca

Comment: And it's getting fixed and reopened by the community in the usual way, I see no need for mod intervention other than guiding comments at this time...

Comment: I'll note that not much of the refining has been from you the OP...  I feel certain if you fix up the question to not be too general/subjective the community will reopen (and not reclose).

Comment: @AndrewM - I strongly suggest that, if you want the question to stay alive and garner the kinds of answers you were originally seeking, you return to it and post some comments or make some edits of your own.  As it is, it seems to me that the latest edits to the question are steering away from your original intent and so I'm inclined to vote-close as "not a real question".

Answer (score 5):

Putting a comment up actually works surprisingly well.  <strike>I</strike>We do try to revisit closed questions.  This also might cause people to *vote* to reopen your question, which would get our attention pretty quickly (mod dashboards and all).

If that doesn't work either put up a meta question or come talk to us in chat, per your preference.  Either of those options will *definitely* get our attention popups network wide and all.

I will go look at your question now ...

Answer (score 3):

As @CRoss has mentioned, there are a few ways you can get your question re-addressed.  I'll try to elaborate a bit on them, though.

1.)  Check to see if the mod and/or other involved users are in the chat room, and hash it out there.  Especially if the mod in question is @CRoss, (he's almost always hanging out there) this should get you a fairly quick response.  It also provides the quickest means of two-way communication if a discussion of any length is required.  When posting your concerns via chat, I suggest posting a description of your issue in one message and a link to your question in its own message.  This allows the link to get "OneBoxed" and makes it more easily recognizable.  Also, make use of the @Mention function here to call out any mods and/or other users involved in closing the thread.  (More on @Mentions later.)

2.)  Post in Meta.  This will give visibility of the issue to most of the community, especially including the moderators and other avid members who may be able to influence the closing/re-opening of the question.  Make sure to include a link to your question.  Put the link on its own line (may or may not be necessary, but just to be sure) so that StackExchange can convert it to a hyperlink with the question title as the display text.  Also, I'm not sure if @Mentions (more on those later) work in question/answer posts like they do in comments or chat, but it wouldn't hurt to try using them to summon the people involved in closing your thread.

3.)  Put a comment on your question.  I make this the last option because, in my opinion, it is least preferable to have potentially lengthy discussions placed in a comment-thread on the main site.  Still, if this is how you'd prefer to do it, one thing I definitely recommend is using the @Mention feature to call on the attention of the mods and/or other users involved in closing the thread.  Their names will be posted at the bottom of your question post if it is closed.  Simply include an @Mention of the user(s) (their username, without any spaces or punctuation, preceded by an @ symbol - like @Iszi, @CRoss, @AndrewM) in your comment.  This will place a message in their global Inbox, which will be flagged on any StackExchange site they visit.